# TeraData REGEXP_SUBSTR date extraction from API Field

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

Community! I am trying to get this syntax to work and I need some assistance. I need to remove everything in the API field and just get the date in the column. I am struggling to accomplish this and not sure how to write this. Any rewrites would be appreciated. Thanks Lads!

[EXTENDED_DATA] API Field:
{"redeterminationDate":"2023-01-01 12:00:00"}

Output Needed as date:
2023-01-01

```
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(EXTENDED_DATA,'[^.-,]+[^0-9]+[^.-,]+[^0-9]+[^.-,]+[^0-9]'1,9) AS DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the consistent structure, you can just substring it out.  We can use `instr` to find the second colon  and add 2 to get our starting position:

```
substr(<column>,instr(<column>,':',1,2)+2,10)
```